# Docker container not accessible from outside

Tags: ubuntu, docker, firewall, iptables

I have setup Docker container with IPtable rules. But Docker container not accessible from outside network.

I have mentioned the iptables rules below. How to access the Docker container from 172.16.8.0/24 network.

For testing purpose, I have installed Apache locally, this Apache access out side network. But docker only not accessible from outside.

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Mon Sep 11 23:34:24 2017
*filter
:INPUT DROP [2758:655810]
:FORWARD DROP [949:56692]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [33529:23757753]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-INGRESS - [0:0]
:DOCKER-ISOLATION - [0:0]
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.30.0/24 -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 172.16.8.0/24 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.168.30.0/24 -p tcp -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-INGRESS
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker_gwbridge -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker_gwbridge -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker_gwbridge ! -o docker_gwbridge -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker_gwbridge -o docker_gwbridge -j DROP
#-A OUTPUT -o ens9 -p tcp -m tcp --sport 80 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-INGRESS -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -i docker_gwbridge -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -i docker0 -o docker_gwbridge -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Sep 11 23:34:24 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Mon Sep 11 23:34:24 2017
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [71640:3047957]
:INPUT ACCEPT [239:12927]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [395:27160]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [424:28860]
:DOCKER - [0:0]
:DOCKER-INGRESS - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER-INGRESS
-A PREROUTING -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A OUTPUT -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER-INGRESS
-A OUTPUT ! -d 127.0.0.0/8 -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j DOCKER
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.17.0.0/16 ! -o docker0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o docker_gwbridge -m addrtype --src-type LOCAL -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.0/16 ! -o docker_gwbridge -j MASQUERADE
-A DOCKER -i docker0 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER -i docker_gwbridge -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-INGRESS -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4000 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.2:4000
-A DOCKER-INGRESS -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5000 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.2:5000
-A DOCKER-INGRESS -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.18.0.2:3000
-A DOCKER-INGRESS -j RETURN
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Sep 11 23:34:24 2017
# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Mon Sep 11 23:34:24 2017
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [151106:48716814]
:INPUT ACCEPT [57104:28465934]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [23732:18002240]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [50500:28830985]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [71261:46656021]
COMMIT
# Completed on Mon Sep 11 23:34:24 2017
```

Comment: how you are running docker container ? And container is dynamic, so no static ip. so expose the port in docker and curl -i http://0.0.0.0:port, add inbound port then you can access from the outside.

Comment: @JinnaBalu, you can set IP to a container using [docker networking](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/).